# Filter mongo document in django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

The project stack is Django + MongoDB (djongo library).
I have product table with data structure like this

```
{
  _id:"qwer1234",
  organization:{...},
  service:{
      "id":1,
      ...
 
  }
}
```

How can I get all documents where service.id will be in array of id ([1,2,3])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  "service.id": {
    "$in": yourArray
  }
})
```

Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5h-1IKTtB6C)